# Query plans for CXPACKET waits

Tags: sql-server, locking, sql-execution-plan

Is there a way to find query plans that are accruing CXPACKET waits?

Those waits are not currently in progress, I saw them in **aggregated** waits statistics (dm_os_wait_stats).

Comment: Moving this question to dba.stackexchange should give you more answers, already voted for that.

Answer (score 1):

I've tested several different approaches, using different scripts from various sources and modifying them to fit our needs. The main problem here is that there is no way, or at least, I can’t find one, to have a script that directly correlates the increase of CXPACKET wait types with a particular query. All the used solutions that I’ve found start by gathering information on the wait types and on the parallelized queries. From here they analyze this information to find which are the possible offending queries.

Finally I came up with the following solution using the known and tested [sp_whoIsActive stored procedure](http://whoisactive.com) and it’s possible to easily recover all the needed information. The approach is to save both information, wait type data and queries execution data, on a table and then query this table to find which query or queries could be the ones affecting the CXPACKET count.

On my setup a job runs each 1 hour executing a script that will call sp_whoIsActive 10 times inside a loop, with a 5s interval between each call. You can leave it running as long as needed to recover as much data as possible. Among many of the parameters that can be used to run this sp I’m using `@delta_interval = 2` and `@destination_table = ‘table_name’`. The `@delta_interval` triggers a special usage of the procedure. Each time it’s called it will run twice, with a 2sec interval and then will add to the results a delta difference of this 2sec. Is a good way to have both historic totals and delta values. And by using `@destination_table` on each run results are saved into a table named `Log_WhoIsActive`. Later you can query this table filtering by any of the columns we can be interested in, in the current case, the wait_info column that holds information about wait types. On the results you will have also the query plan, the query itself and more data that can be useful for troubleshooting. My destination table name is `sh_wait_stats`.

Here a sample query filtering by CXPACKET on the resulting table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   dbo.Log_WhoIsActive
WHERE  wait_info LIKE '%CXPACKET%'
ORDER BY collection_time DESC
```

Sample of wait_info column:

> (4x: 2/3/5ms)RUNNABLE, (3x: 25983/25986/25988ms)CXPACKET:21, (2x: 2/46ms)CXPACKET:13, (1x: 54390ms)CXPACKET:2, (1x: 27ms)CXPACKET:9

Where:

> (Ax: Bms/Cms/Dms)E
>          A is the number of waiting tasks currently waiting on resource type E. B/C/D are wait times, in milliseconds. If only one thread is waiting, its wait time will be shown as B. If two tasks are waiting, each of their wait times will be shown (B/C). If three or more tasks are waiting, the minimum, average, and maximum wait times will be shown (B/C/D). If wait type E is a page latch wait and the page is of a "special" type (e.g. PFS, GAM, SGAM), the page type will be identified. If wait type E is CXPACKET, the nodeId from the query plan will be identified

By taking a look into the results is possible to have the queries with the most CXPACKET wait type and that are repeatedly called. There is a big chance that those queries are the ones causing the rise of the CXPACKET wait type.

Here are the scripts I used:

```
/**********************************************************************************
 * Step 1: Create a @destination_table
 *          
 * First, create your destination table. Sp_whoIsActive lets you generate a destination table easily.
 * Here is a basic version which includes the current date in the table name, as well as flags to get transaction 
 * info (tlog write info and duration) and query plans:
 ***********************************************************************************/
DECLARE @destination_table VARCHAR(4000) = 'dbo.Log_WhoIsActive'
        ,@schema VARCHAR(4000)
        ,@SQL NVARCHAR(500);

IF OBJECT_ID(@destination_table) IS NOT NULL 
BEGIN
    SELECT @SQL = 'DROP TABLE ' + @destination_table + '';
    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
END

EXEC [sp_WhoIsActive]
        @filter = '', 
        @filter_type = 'login',
        @not_filter = 'SQLSEARCHSERVER2',
        @not_filter_type = 'login',
        @get_task_info = 2,
        @get_plans = 2,
        @get_additional_info = 1,
        @show_sleeping_spids = 0,
        @delta_interval = 2,
        @output_column_list = '[dd%][session_id][query_plan][login_name][wait_info][tasks][status][host_name][database_name][program_name][sql_text][additional_info][tran_log%][cpu%][temp%][block%][reads%][writes%][context%][physical%][locks][%]',
        @RETURN_SCHEMA = 1, 
        @SCHEMA = @schema OUTPUT;

SET @schema = REPLACE(@schema, '<table_name>', @destination_table);

EXEC (@schema);

/***************************************************************************************
 * Step 2: Create a loop to periodically log data
 * Adding this step on a job makes it to run periodically to keep historical data
 * You need to need to make sure to specify the same parameters for sp_whoisactive in this loop, so the output matches the schema
 * for the table you’ve created.
 * This does 10 runs with a 5 second wait between runs. Depending on what’s going on, I change those numbers accordingly.
 ****************************************************************************************/
DECLARE @destination_table VARCHAR(4000) = 'dbo.Log_WhoIsActive'
        ,@msg NVARCHAR(1000)
        ,@numberOfRuns INT = 10;

WHILE @numberOfRuns > 0
BEGIN
    EXEC [sp_WhoIsActive]
            @filter = '', 
            @filter_type = 'login',
            @not_filter = 'SQLSEARCHSERVER2',
            @not_filter_type = 'login',
            @get_task_info = 2,
            @get_plans = 2,
            @get_additional_info = 1,
            @show_sleeping_spids = 0,
            @delta_interval = 5,
            @output_column_list = '[dd%][session_id][query_plan][login_name][wait_info][tasks][status][host_name][database_name][program_name][sql_text][additional_info][tran_log%][cpu%][temp%][block%][reads%][writes%][context%][physical%][locks][%]',
            @destination_table = @destination_table;

    SET @numberOfRuns = @numberOfRuns - 1 ;

    IF @numberOfRuns > 0
    BEGIN
         WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:05'
    END
END

/************************************************************************************
* Use this script to read data from historical table  
************************************************************************************/

DECLARE @max_increment_id INT 

--Determine most-recent increment_id 
SELECT @max_increment_id = MAX(increment_id) FROM dbo.sh_wait_stats 

--Present Waits results for period 
SELECT DOWS1.wait_type,
       (DOWS1.waiting_tasks_count - DOWS2.waiting_tasks_count) AS [diff_waiting_tasks_count],
       (DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) AS [wait_time_ms],
       DOWS1.max_wait_time_ms,
       (DOWS1.signal_wait_time_ms - DOWS2.signal_wait_time_ms) AS  [diff_signal_wait_time_ms],
       DATEDIFF(ms, DOWS2.capture_time, DOWS1.capture_time) AS [diff_elapsed_time_ms],
       DOWS1.capture_time  AS [last_time_stamp],
       DOWS2.capture_time  AS [previous_time_stamp]
FROM   (
           SELECT wait_type,
                  waiting_tasks_count,
                  wait_time_ms,
                  max_wait_time_ms,
                  signal_wait_time_ms,
                  capture_time,
                  increment_id
           FROM   dbo.sh_wait_stats
           WHERE  increment_id = @max_increment_id
       )                   AS DOWS1
       INNER JOIN (
                SELECT wait_type,
                       waiting_tasks_count,
                       wait_time_ms,
                       max_wait_time_ms,
                       signal_wait_time_ms,
                       capture_time,
                       increment_id
                FROM   dbo.sh_wait_stats
                WHERE  increment_id = (@max_increment_id - 1)
            )              AS DOWS2
            ON  DOWS1.wait_type = DOWS2.wait_type
WHERE  (DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) > 0
AND DOWS1.wait_type NOT IN (
        'CLR_SEMAPHORE', 'LAZYWRITER_SLEEP', 'RESOURCE_QUEUE', 'SLEEP_TASK',
        'SLEEP_SYSTEMTASK', 'SQLTRACE_BUFFER_FLUSH', 'WAITFOR', 'LOGMGR_QUEUE',
        'CHECKPOINT_QUEUE', 'REQUEST_FOR_DEADLOCK_SEARCH', 'XE_TIMER_EVENT', 'BROKER_TO_FLUSH',
        'BROKER_TASK_STOP', 'CLR_MANUAL_EVENT', 'CLR_AUTO_EVENT', 'DISPATCHER_QUEUE_SEMAPHORE',
        'FT_IFTS_SCHEDULER_IDLE_WAIT', 'XE_DISPATCHER_WAIT', 'XE_DISPATCHER_JOIN', 'BROKER_EVENTHANDLER',
        'TRACEWRITE', 'FT_IFTSHC_MUTEX', 'SQLTRACE_INCREMENTAL_FLUSH_SLEEP',
        'BROKER_RECEIVE_WAITFOR', 'ONDEMAND_TASK_QUEUE', 'DBMIRROR_EVENTS_QUEUE',
        'DBMIRRORING_CMD', 'BROKER_TRANSMITTER', 'SQLTRACE_WAIT_ENTRIES',
        'SLEEP_BPOOL_FLUSH', 'SQLTRACE_LOCK')
ORDER BY
       (DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) DESC;

--Present Waits results for period 
WITH Waits AS 
(
    SELECT DOWS1.wait_type,
           ((DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) / 1000) AS [wait_time_s],
           100. * (DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) / SUM(DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) 
           OVER()  AS pct,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) DESC) AS 
           rn
    FROM   (
               SELECT wait_type,
                      waiting_tasks_count,
                      wait_time_ms,
                      max_wait_time_ms,
                      signal_wait_time_ms,
                      capture_time,
                      increment_id
               FROM   dbo.sh_wait_stats
               WHERE  increment_id = @max_increment_id
           )       AS DOWS1
           INNER JOIN (
                    SELECT wait_type,
                           waiting_tasks_count,
                           wait_time_ms,
                           max_wait_time_ms,
                           signal_wait_time_ms,
                           capture_time,
                           increment_id
                    FROM   dbo.sh_wait_stats
                    WHERE  increment_id = (@max_increment_id - 1)
                )  AS DOWS2
                ON  DOWS1.wait_type = DOWS2.wait_type
    WHERE  (DOWS1.wait_time_ms - DOWS2.wait_time_ms) > 0
) 
SELECT W1.wait_type,
       CAST(W1.wait_time_s AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS wait_time_s,
       CAST(W1.pct AS DECIMAL(12, 2))  AS pct,
       CAST(SUM(W2.pct) AS DECIMAL(12, 2)) AS running_pct
FROM   Waits                           AS W1
       INNER JOIN Waits                AS W2
            ON  W2.rn <= W1.rn
GROUP BY
       W1.rn,
       W1.wait_type,
       W1.wait_time_s,
       W1.pct
HAVING SUM(W2.pct) - W1.pct < 95; -- percentage threshold;
```

Answer (score 0):

Waits are associated to process id, not to query plan. The same query plan will wait different resources depending the load of your servers and network.

You can do this query:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.sysprocesses
```

To see who is doing what and which wait is involved for each process.

After reading some documentation I found this useful post:
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/23eeb821-2a42-429d-8d94-aee96224701d

It involves `dm_exec_requests` view which contains `wait_type` (and time) you are looking for.

Comment: The link doesn't  help to find what I'm looking for, quoting for the author `Whenever I execute sp_who2, I get some questions what command is executing currently. If a command taking much  time, for analysis have to check the execution plan. Also when i do a back up or restore, I do like to check the percentage completed of that operation. Instead of doing different steps to get these details, thought of extending the sp_who2 SP itself to provide these details.` Nevertheless, we are currently using sp_whoIsActive that returns lot more of information on who, what and when.